# how to create png chart images using php?

Tags: php, laravel, gd, sparklines

i have and api which returns history rates about crypto currencies.

i want to generate and save sparkline charts like this:

[image]

please look at: `https://coinmarketcap.com/`, are this type of image charts already saved in server? or they will generate every time in every call??

any way...
i dont know what should i do and how.

i tried some ways but i cant make that tranparent (png)

my tried way:

```
    $size = '200x60';
    $back = '#fbefef';
    $line = '#f73536';
    $fill = '#fbefef';
    $data = isset($test) ? $test : array();

    list($w, $h) = explode('x', $size);
    $w = floor(max(50, min(800, $w)));
    $h = !strstr($size, 'x') ? $w : floor(max(20, min(800, $h)));
    $t = 2.3;
    $s = 5;

    $w *= $s;
    $h *= $s;
    $t *= $s;

    $salt = 'v1.0.1';
    $hash = md5($salt);

    $data = (count($data) < 2) ? array_fill(0, 2, $data[0]) : $data;
    $count = count($data);
    $step = $w / ($count - 1);

    $min = min($data);
    $max = max($data);
    if ($max != $min) {
        foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
            $data[$k] -= $min;
        }
        $max = max($data);
    }


    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

    list($r, $g, $b) = $this->hexToRgb($line);
    $fg = imagecolorallocate($im, $r, $g, $b);
    list($r, $g, $b) = $this->hexToRgb($fill);
    $lg = imagecolorallocate($im, $r, $g, $b);

    imagecolortransparent($im, $bg);
    imagesavealpha($im, true);


    imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg);
    imagesetthickness($im, $t);

    foreach ($data as $k => $v)
    {
        $v = $v > 0 ? round($v / $max * $h) : 0;
        $data[$k] = max($s, min($v, $h - $s));
    }

    $x1 = 0;
    $y1 = $h - $data[0];
    $line = array();
    $poly = array(0, $h + 50, $x1, $y1);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        $x2 = $x1 + $step;
        $y2 = $h - $data[$i];
        array_push($line, array($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2));
        array_push($poly, $x2, $y2);
        $x1 = $x2;
        $y1 = $y2;
    }
    array_push($poly, $x2, $h + 50);

    imagefilledpolygon($im, $poly, $count + 2, $lg);

    foreach ($line as $k => $v)
    {
        list($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2) = $v;
        imageline($im, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $fg);
    }

    $om = imagecreatetruecolor($w / $s, $h / $s);
    imagecopyresampled($om, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w / $s, $h / $s, $w, $h);
    imagedestroy($im);

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="sparkline_' . time() . substr(microtime(), 2, 3) . '.png"');
    header('ETag: ' . $hash);
    header('Accept-Ranges: none');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=604800, must-revalidate');
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime('+7 days')));
    imagepng($om);
    imagedestroy($om);
```

help me, thank you.

Comment: There are libraries to generate charts available in many languages...

Comment: unfortunately there is no any good library for php exactly like my example

Comment: @K1-Aria Why would you need a pure PHP library for that anyway? Any JS library will do for this use case, for example something like Chart.js.

Comment: @Loupeznik

because we have something about 7000 currency and we want to show those charts. its better to be a picture pre saved